# How to add extension to doxygen

Tags: javascript, doxygen

I am new to using doxygen (love it) and I need to be able to document javascript. I looked under the extensions tab on the doxygen homepage and it told of an extension to document javascript; however, I don't know how to add/enable extensions. How do you add extensions and then make sure they are used? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the extensions for javascript are filters, they parse javascript source code and create a C++ like (not real C++) file which then can be parsed by doxygen!

You can try them out by downloading und running them (they are scripts) and look if they work properly (not yet working for my files..).

If you find one, all you have to do is change the settings in the Doxyfile (configuration file) under FILTER_PATTERNS.

have a look a this:

http://coherent-labs.com/blog/documenting-javascript-with-doxygen/

and this:

https://github.com/schteppe/ammo.js-demos/tree/master/doc